# This code is supposed to produce a file called "Data.in" , but doesn't produce anything

Tags: c++, visual-c++

this code is supposed to produce a file called `data.in` with random binary values that I'm supposed to read and produce flags. However, using several IDE's, nothing is produced. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int createTestData(int flags[], int dataSize) {
    ofstream binary_file("data.in", ios::out | ios::binary);

    if (!binary_file) {
        cout << "The file data.in could not open for a binary write.\n" << endl;
        return (1);
    } else if (!binary_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(flags),
                                  sizeof(int) * 3)) {
        cout << "Write failure 1 in createTestData().\n" << endl;
        return (1);
    } else if (!binary_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dataSize),
                                  sizeof(int))) {
        cout << "Write failure 2 in createTestData().\n" << endl;
        return (1);
    }

    int val;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (flags[i] == 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataSize; j++) {
                val = rand();

                if (!binary_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val),
                                       sizeof(int))) {
                    cout << "Write failure 3 in createTestData().\n" << endl;
                    return (1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    binary_file.close();
    return (0);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int dataFlags[3];
    int dataSize = 0;

    if (argc != 5) {
        cout << "\nUsage: " << argv[0]
             << " sstFlag sFlag sshFlag dataArraySize\n" << endl;
        return (1);
    } else {
        dataFlags[0] = atoi(argv[1]);
        dataFlags[1] = atoi(argv[2]);
        dataFlags[2] = atoi(argv[3]);

        dataSize = atoi(argv[4]);

        createTestData(dataFlags, dataSize);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't being produced, not that it's just in the wrong directory?

Comment: I just ran this on my system and it did indeed produce an output file. I assume something else is wrong.

Comment: What directory is `data.in` supposed to be in?  Maybe it isn't in the directory you think it should be.  Why not test by giving a full path name instead of just `data.in`?

Comment: when I put in C:\... then the rest of the path that the project is saved to, it will not compile.. if I do the path without the C:\, and the rest of it, it compiles but still no file. If I search my system, no Data.in file exists

Comment: You need to escape the \ character by doing C:\\.

Comment: when i do the double slash it stops the error from coming up, but still no file... about ready to throw this laptop through my window!

Comment: Download process monitor from sysinternals (microsoft), and trace what the application is doing. It's probably creating a file, you just can't tell where. This will also help you see errors that you may not be noticing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013, data.in was produced in

`C:\Users\<user>\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\<project-name>\<project-name>`

This is the same folder that your main .cpp file is.

Comment: I understand that's how it's SUPPOSED to work, it's just not working here. Not sure what's to blame, it's getting very frustrating.